# Импортировать метод из файла js, NUXT, VUE

Tags: vue.js, typescript, nuxt.js

Я использую vue-chartjs в своем nuxt-приложении. Поставил его как плагин и внутри него прописал для себя необходимую конфигурацию.

Я ожидал, что при импорте плагина в свой компонент `import LineChart from "~/plugins/LineChart.js";`
, метод в моем компоненте будет инициализироваться из моего плагина. Но я получаю ошибку `Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Element | Element[] | Vue | Vue[]'. Property 'method' does not exist on type 'Element'.`

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: что такое LineChart.js и как он используется в Вашем примере?

Answer (score 0):

не зарегистрировал плагин в nuxt.config. Это решило мою проблему с ошибками